# Grails default value for domain class attribute of user defined type

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class Plan which is like:

```
class Plan{
  String name
  static constraints={
    name(unique:true,nullable:false)
  }
}
```

Another domain class is User:

```
class User{
 // Other attribures and code
 // ....
 Plan plan
 static constraints = {
   // other constraints..
   plan(nullable:false, defaultValue: Plan.findByName("default"))
 }
}
```

Above code gives me error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [mypackage.Plan] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
at mypackage.User$__clinit__closure1.doCall(User.groovy:31)
```

The line above in error is

```
plan(nullable:true,defaultValue: Plan.findByName("default"))
```

Also I have defined the default plan in BootStrap.groovy:

```
if(!Plan.findByName("default")){
            new Plan(name: "default",brandPartner: null,secRole: null).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
            log.info("initPlans: No default plan found, hence created a new default plan!")
}
```

So how should I set the default value for plan attribute(which is of user defined type)?

Answer (score 1):

Use an interceptor instead of constraint:

```
class User{
  Plan plan
  static beforeInsert = {
    if( !plan ) Plan.withTransaction {
      plan = Plan.findByName 'default'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this assign null or the default value to the already existing User class objects if plan attribute is added later?

Comment: for already extisting user you would have to add `beforeUpdate` interceptor with the same code